# How do I parse an array in antlr?

Tags: antlr4

I'm working on parsing PDF content streams. I'm having trouble defining an array. The definition of an array in the PDF reference (PDF 32000-1:2008) is:

> An array object is a one-dimensional collection of objects arranged sequentially. …an array’s elements may be any combination of numbers, strings, dictionaries, or any other objects, including other arrays. An array may have zero elements.
>
> An array shall be written as a sequence of objects enclosed in SQUARE BRACKETS (using LEFT SQUARE BRACKET (5Bh) and RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET (5Dh)).
>
> EXAMPLE: [549 3.14 false (Ralph) /SomeName]

Here's a stripped-down version of my grammar:

```
grammar PdfStream;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

content : stat* ;

stat
    : array
    | string
    ;

array: ARRAY ;
string: STRING ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

ARRAY: '[' (ARRAY | DICTIONARY | OBJECT)* ']' ;

DICTIONARY: '<<' (NAME (ARRAY | DICTIONARY | OBJECT))*  '>>' ;

NULL: 'null' ;

BOOLEAN: ('true'|'false') ;

NUMBER: ('+' | '-')? (INT | FLOAT) ;

STRING: (LITERAL_STRING | HEX_STRING) ;

NAME: '/' ID ;

INT: DIGIT+ ;

LITERAL_STRING: '(' .*? ')' ;

HEX_STRING: '<' [0-9A-Za-z]+ '>' ;

FLOAT:  DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
     |         '.' DIGIT+
     ;

OBJECT
    : NULL
    | BOOLEAN
    | NUMBER
    | STRING
    | NAME
    ;

fragment DIGIT:   [0-9] ;

// All characters except whitespace and defined delimiters ()<>[]{}/%
ID: ~[ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000()<>[\]{}/%]+ ;

WS: [ \t\r\n\u000C\u0000]+ -> skip ; // PDF defines six whitespace characters
```

And here's the test file I'm processing.

```
<AE93>
(String1)
( String2 )
[]
[549 3.14 false (Ralph) /SomeName]
```

When I process the file with `grun PdfStream tokens -tokens stream.txt` I get this output:

```
line 5:0 token recognition error at: '[549 '
line 5:33 token recognition error at: ']'
[@0,0:5='<AE93>',<STRING>,1:0]
[@1,7:15='(String1)',<STRING>,2:0]
[@2,17:27='( String2 )',<STRING>,3:0]
[@3,29:30='[]',<ARRAY>,4:0]
[@4,37:40='3.14',<NUMBER>,5:5]
[@5,42:46='false',<BOOLEAN>,5:10]
[@6,48:54='(Ralph)',<STRING>,5:16]
[@7,56:64='/SomeName',<NAME>,5:24]
[@8,67:66='<EOF>',<EOF>,6:0]
```

What's wrong with my grammar that's causing the token recognition errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[549 3.14 false (Ralph) /SomeName]` isn't recognized as an `ARRAY` because it contains spaces and the rule for `ARRAY` does not allow any spaces. If you want spaces to be ignored between the elements of an array, you should turn it into a parser rule instead of a lexer rule (the same applies to `DICTIONARY`).

You'll also need to make `OBJECT` a parser rule because otherwise it will never be matched because any input that matches, say, `NUMBER` will always produce a `NUMBER` token instead of an `OBJECT` token because `OBJECT` comes last in the grammar. Generally you never want multiple lexer rules where everything that can be matched by one of them can also always be matched by at least one other. This also means that you want to turn `INT` and `FLOAT` into `fragment`s.

Comment: Obviously I need to keep studying the ANTLR 4 Reference book to get a better grasp of what should be a parser rule and what should be a lexer rule. This was a huge help and got me up and running. Thanks.

Comment: @SSteve as a rule of thumb, you can ask yourself whether you'd want to allow and ignore whitespace inside of the rule or not. As another rule of thumb, you rarely want lexer rules to be recursive (sometimes you do though). And as I wrote in my answer, you don't want lexer rules to overlap in a way that makes some of them redundant. A rule of thumb for that would be that you don't want lexer rules that are simply alternatives of other lexer rules (i.e. `A : B | C | D`).